# How may I output file size in both bytes and MB?

Tags: files

I can think of a few different ways to get the file size in bytes OR in MB.

```
    du -h ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso
    296M    ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso
    stat --printf='%s %n \n' ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso
    309329920 ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso 
    find -maxdepth 1 -name "ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso" -printf "%s %P\n"
    309329920 ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso
    ls -lh ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 295M May  3 00:35 ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso
    ls -l ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 309329920 May  3 00:35 ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso
```

How do I get both on one line?
i.e.

```
296M    309329920    ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
stat -c "%s %s %n" ubuntu-mini-remix-16.04-amd64.iso | awk '{ byte =$1 /1024/1024; print byte "M\t"$2"\t"$3 }'
```

`awk` will calculate filesize in MB by divided filesize with `/1024/1024` and display all.